# Detecting browser from within Chromeframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet, google-chrome-frame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Chrome Frame conditional comments possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908896/is-chrome-frame-conditional-comments-possible)

I have a bookmarklet that I want users to be able to install in all browser.  Just a simple link with some javascript behind it to be used like pintrest or evernote... It works in all browsers (2 version back) except in IE when chromeframe is running (we require chromeframe for older version of IE).

In chromeframe you can not drag the link to your favorites toolbar but I can open a popup in native IE and display the link (which can then be installed/dragged to the toolbar).

I just don't know how to detect if I am running inside of a chromeframe instance (detecting IE without chromeframe running is super easy with `CFInstall` or writing it myself).  The `userAgent` I see from within chromeframe is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11` which is of no use as far as I can tell. I have also tried a few dozen combinations of `<!--[if IE]>` and those seem to all be flops too.

The only solution I have right now is to have the server catch the initial `userAgent` and feed it back during rendering.  I don't mind modifying the server code but it feels dirty not being able to do the check via a client side only tester.

Comment: I just found [window.externalHost](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/understanding-chrome-frame-user-agent#TOC-From-the-script-on-the-web-page) with the same answer.  So yes, this looks like a dup... is the proper edict to delete this one?

Comment: If you feel that the duplicate is hard to find, you could keep the question, so that future Googlers can find the answer (via your question) more easily. Otherwise, deleting your question would be most appropriate.